# Why is it showing that the function is not defined? It does log the results in console, I am just trying to list the first name

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have a restAPI backend that I am trying to get data from. I am using NodeJS but for some reason, the data loads in the console as JSON but when I try to print it in the new webpage I get an error

```
TypeError: /Final part 2/views/pages/letseat.ejs:11
    9|         </div>
    10|         <!-- Right here it takes every value that we got back and then puts it into a list item -->
 >> 11|             <% userlist.forEach(function(userlist) { %>
    12|                 <ul class="list-group list-group-numbered">
    13|                     <input type="checkbox" name=<%= userlist.firstname %>
    14|                     <li class="list-group-item"><%= userlist['firstname'] %>, By: <%= userlist['lastname' ]%> </li>

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'forEach')
```

But I do get the data in JSON in the terminal

```
  data: [
    {
      firstname: 'John',
      lastname: 'Boyle',
      numberofplaces: null,
      user_id: 1
    },
    {
      firstname: 'Ruben',
      lastname: 'Holt',
      numberofplaces: null,
      user_id: 3
    },
    {
      firstname: 'Tim',
      lastname: 'Diaz',
      numberofplaces: null,
      user_id: 4
    },
    {
      firstname: 'Tony',
      lastname: 'Santiago',
      numberofplaces: null,
      user_id: 2
    },
    {
      firstname: 'Scully',
      lastname: 'Smith',
      numberofplaces: null,
      user_id: 5
    }
  ]
```

The function that I am using to render the page is

```
    <% userlist.forEach(function(songlist) { %>
        <ul class="list-group list-group-numbered">
            <input type="checkbox" name=<%= userlist.firstname %>
            <li class="list-group-item"><%= userlist['firstname'] %>, By: <%= userlist['lastname' ]%> </li>
        </ul>
    <% }); %>
```

Lastly this is the API route

```
app.get('/process_form', function(req, res){
    // create a variable to hold the username parsed from the request body
    // Now we will use the token wiht the name that the user entered
    // For this we will use the axios method to return the result
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/getuser')
    .then((response)=>{
        var userlist = response.data.results;
        console.log(userlist);
        res.render('pages/letseat', {
            userlist: userlist
        });
```

Please give me some guidance I've been stuck on this for 3 hours!!!

Comment: `var userlist = response.data;`. Also in your `forEach` you should be using `songlist.firstname`, etc. Not `userlist.firstname`

Comment: I changed that variable and just updated that code, Thank you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access a property that doesn't exist and returning that caused it to be undefined.

```js
    var userlist = response.data.results
//                               ^^^^^^^
```

`response.data` is already an array you wanted. So you gotta change to

```js
    var userlist = response.data
```

Comment: so I am not supposed to have the results? Sorry my professor went really fast in class so I am a bit confused. So I thought that the when I assigned response.data.results, it returns the json object and that is saved in the variable user list

Comment: You are not supposed to access the property `results`. It doesn't exist, that's why userlist is undefined in the EJS file.

Comment: OK that resolved my issue, thank you so much